# Xpath insert sequence of nodes under a node - Java

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I am trying to add sequence of nodes under a node, below is my reference xml:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>Bulkload</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <trans_status>0</trans_status>
    <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
  </info>
  <connection>
    <name>con_name</name>
    <server>server</server>
    <type>SYBASE</type>
    <access>Native</access>
    <database>database</database>
    <port>port</port>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>Encrypted xyz</password>
  
  </connection>

  <step>
    <name>Extract</name>
    <type>TextFileOutput</type>
    <fields>

**HERE**
<field>
</field>
 </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>300</xloc>
      <yloc>168</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>
</transformation>
```

I want to add below xml block inside field tag:

```css
<field>
            <name>field_name</name>
            <type>Integer</type>
            <format>&#x23;&#x3b;-&#x23;</format>
            <currency/>
            <decimal>.</decimal>
            <group>,</group>
            <nullif/>
            <trim_type>none</trim_type>
            <length>9</length>
            <precision>0</precision>
</field>
```

My requirement is to create new xml documents from the above template. I only found a method in Xpath to insert node before a node so I updated my template and added a blank field node in it inside **fields** node and with that I was able to insert a node with the below code:

```
        File dest =new File("H:\\Project_Documents\\reference.ktr");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            Document document = builder.parse(dest);
            XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

            NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("field");
            Text a = document.createTextNode("Anup");
            Element p =document.createElement("field");
            p.appendChild(a);
nodes.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(p, nodes.item(0));
```

but again I faced the dame problem for child nodes i.e name, type, format, etc. Could anybody please show me a way to achieve my purpose?

If I cannot achieve it with Xpath then which parser I should use?

Comment: Why is that tagged as XPath, I don't see any use of XPath. And what exactly is the problem, creating those nodes you want to insert using the W3C DOM, or inserting a newly created node at a specific position?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your comment. I am using Xpath to insert a node that's why I tagged xpath. I want to insert newly created node inside a node(in the place of **HERE** ).

Comment: I apologize if I made it confusing, I am from non English country.

Comment: XPath does not insert any nodes, it only selects them. And while you create `XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath()` in your code, you never use it. As for creating the new element, you have that with `Element p =document.createElement("field");`, as for inserting it, you have `insertBefore`. So what is the exact problem?

Comment: oh ok, so that means I cannot use Xpath to insert nodes. What would you recommend to insert nodes in xml ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution, which works:

You have to manage two XML Documents, find the tag you want, and replace.

With XPath you can select more precisely, but no use there.

1 get a DOM for your global XML

```
Document document= ...
```

2 get the node you want to insert

```
Document document_to_insert = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml_to_insert))); // ...

//GET NODE field
NodeList nodes_field_to_insert=document_to_insert.getElementsByTagName("field");

Element node_field_to_insert=null;

for(int i=0; i<nodes_field_to_insert.getLength(); i++)
{
 Node the_node = nodes_field_to_insert.item(i);

 // WE TAKE THE FIRST ONE
 if(the_node instanceof Element)
    {
     node_field_to_insert=(Element) the_node;
     break;
    }
}
```

3 go to the field node in the global XML

4 replace inside the node

```
// GET NODE field
NodeList nodes=document.getElementsByTagName("field");

for(int i=0; i<nodes.getLength(); i++)
{
   Node the_node = nodes.item(i);

   if(the_node instanceof Element)
     {
     Element a_child = (Element) the_node;
     Node newNode = document.importNode(node_field_to_insert, true);

     // FATHER
     Node the_parent=a_child.getParentNode();
     the_parent.replaceChild(newNode,a_child);

     // WE STOP
     break;
 }
}
```